# how can I get end of file in java using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am getting input from Scanner and system.in and I want to get the enter from output. I have a loop as while(keyboard.hasnext()) do something. But when I hit enter it doesn't get anything and after that it doesn't get any input too but the program is still running. So I am stuck in this loop. Help me out guys.

Comment: wont keyboard.hasnext !="\n" solve the problem ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String input;
input = in.nextLine();
if (input.equals("") {
 done = true; //or do smth else
}
```